# Creating a PDO instance causes error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to use PDO to connect to mysql, But when i try to create an instance of the PDO it causes the code to break. I have tried putting it in a try and catch, but it still breaks the code/ i get a page saying "The localhost page isn’t working"

```
protected $conn;

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Mydatabase";
$this->conn = new PDO($dsn, "admin", "test2016");
```

If i try to connect to mysql like this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "test2016");
```

it works fine.

I am not sure why new PDO is causing that error.

```
class Database {

protected $conn;

function __construct() {
    $this->init();
}

function init(){
   try{
    $this->conn= $this->connectDB("localhost","Mydatabase","admin","test2016"); // the here
    $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
   }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

}

function connectDB($servername,$database,$username,$password){

   $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Mydatabase";
   return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);// i am not sure why new pdo is the cause of the problem

   // $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

    //if (!$conn) {
      // die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    //}

    //echo "Connected successfully";

}
```

Comment: why is there mysqli_ and PDO here? If you're mixing those, you can't.

Comment: I hope u r using semicolon here `protected $conn`

Comment: I am not using them both at the same time. I am trying to use just one of them which is the PDO. I am was using testing if mysql dose work. @Fred-ii-

Comment: @devpro i am using the simicolon in the actually code. I forgot to put that in question. i'll edit that now.

Comment: **We are not sure what error it produces** Would you like to tell us?

Comment: Plz use Php error_reporting() and chk errors

Comment: @devpro how do i use that?

Comment: Your title said _Creating a PDO instance causes error_ **Tell us what errors**

Comment: After a `protected $conn;` I'd expect a method if you want to use `$this->conn`. This is wrong or there are a lot of lines missing...

Comment: The code is actually small but i wanted to make the code small and narrow it down to the problem. @jeroen

Comment: Look the code you have shown makes no sense, you have left too much out. And you wont answer the obvious question about what error is produced. So I am off to do something more productive

Comment: @RiggsFolly it just throws the page  "The localhost page isn’t working" because of the "new PDO($dsn, "admin", "test2016");" this line

Comment: _The code is actually small but i wanted to make the code small and narrow it down to the problem_ So you means this is ALL the code, if so, its not valid PHP, so you have made it too narrow

Comment: i'll edit the question and include class and place a comment where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, you are trying to call a method on an undefined variable:

```
function init(){
   try{
     $this->conn= $this->connectDB("localhost","Mydatabase","admin","test2016"); // the here
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Should be:

```
function init(){
   try{
     $this->conn= $this->connectDB("localhost","Mydatabase","admin","test2016"); // the here
     $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     ^^^^^ here
```

Comment: is it? But i am sure i am creating the PDO in the connectDB method. I am trying to figure why that is undefined now.

Comment: I see what you mean and i have changed it to `$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` 
and i am still showing me "The localhost page isn’t working"

Answer (score -2):

This is a very basic example that works for what you're trying to do, in think.

```
class Database {

    protected $conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }

    public function init() {
        try{
            $this->conn = $this->connectDB("localhost","Mydatabase","admin","test2016");
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            if (!$this->conn) {
                throw new Exception("Connection failed: ");
            }
            echo 'Connected';
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function connectDB($servername, $database, $username, $password) {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$database;
        return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    }

}
```

If this class is not working for you, please test your server information, or even server status.

I hope this help you a little.

Comment: I have tried it this way but it's still something to do with creating an instance of the pdo. I am guessing I don't have the pdo drive or I am missing a set up. (I am on a Mac using mamp) it's a nightmare doing set ups on a Mac >[